# Is distance between two graphs defined somehow?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition, graph-isomorphism

If the two graphs are isomorphic, then their distance is zero. And this distance increases, if vertices or edges are added or removed to/from one of the graphs.

Does this "distance" have a special name, or definition?

This distance function should return the minimal number of steps, to transform one graph to an another given graph, using edge/vertex adding/removing

The graph may be directed or not, but the edges aren't weighted (in my case)

---

**Note**: I don't ask you for an algorithm which calculates is. I'm just looking for the name (and the correct definition) of this thing, which I call "distance"

Comment: It seems like you want the [Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance), adapted for (labelled?) graphs rather than for arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for graph edit distance. This has actually been discussed on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399597/edit-distance-between-two-graphs).